# Create class from inherited class instance

Tags: python, inheritance

I have simple class:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        # there can be many fields

    def bar(self):
        print(f"WOOF {self.size}")
```

And two methods I cannot modify:

```
def get_dog():
    return Dog("big")

def foo(dog: Dog):
    dog.bar()
```

Now my goal is to expand functionality of `Dog.bar` so the `foo` function will call modified version.

```
class BigDog(Dog):
    def bar(self):
        print("WOFWOF")
```

So I search for a way of creating `BigDog` from a `Dog` instance taken from the `get_dog`. The problem is I don't know what attributes are in `Dog` class and what is the implementation on `get_dog`.

The simplest way I considered was:

```
class BigDog:
    def __init__(self, dog: Dog):
        self.dog = dog
   
    def bar(self):
       ...
```

But now a `Dog` is not a dog and mypy complains.

How to properly implement `BigDog` to be subclass of `Dog` and allow it to be initialized from the `Dog` instance?

Comment: you don't want to use a foo/bar example without bar...

Comment: Why do you have to use the instanced returned by `get_dog`? You can pass any instance of `BigDog` to `foo`, as any instance of `BigDog` is an instance of `Dog`.

Comment: Yvain my bad, I fixed that :D  @chepner It's some legacy implementation of special object I cannot touch.

Comment: Can you just set `Dog = BigDog` in the scope where `get_dog` is defined?

Comment: @chepner If I could everything would be simple. Unfortunately I have not access to implementation of `get_dog` nor `foo`. I don't know what is inside, I only now the protocol.

Comment: If you don't know how `get_dog` creates an instance of `Dog`, I don't see there is anything you can do. It seems like, ultimately, *something* must call `Dog`.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably inadvisable, but actually achievable:

```python
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def bark(self):
        print(f"{self.name} says woof!")

class BigDog(Dog):
    def bark(self):
        print(f"{self.name} lets out a deafening growl.")

import typing

def give_steroids(dog: Dog) -> BigDog:
    assert type(dog) is Dog
    dog.__class__ = BigDog
    return typing.cast(BigDog, dog)

give_steroids(Dog("Clifford")).bark()
```

This does not create a new object, but modifies an existing object so that descriptor dispatch is done through the derived class; this may or may not be close enough.

There are some restrictions: if the base class uses [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots), your derived class should set its own `__slots__` to the empty tuple.  This applies to all intermediate derived classes as well.  Otherwise assignment to `.__class__` will raise a `TypeError`.

```python
class Dog:
    __slots__ = ('name',)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def bark(self):
        print(f"{self.name} says woof!")

class BigDog(Dog):
    __slots__ = ()

    def bark(self):
        print(f"{self.name} lets out a deafening growl.")

class LargeDog(Dog):
    def bark(self):
        print(f"{self.name} lets out a sound so powerful, you momentarily faint.")
        
puppy = Dog("Clifford")
puppy.__class__ = BigDog      # OK
puppy.__class__ = LargeDog    # TypeError
```